# How to display all rows in Java using JTable? [solved]

Tags: java, jtable

I would like to ask how to display all rows in Java using JTable.
I tried using a while condition inside is a result.next() to be evaluated.

I tried printing it using System.out.println and it display all records however when I tried it on JTable it only displays the last row.

```
while(results.next()) {
    
    String id = results.getString("id");
    String date_collected = results.getString("date_collected");
    String date_disposed = results.getString("date_disposed");
    String person_in_charged = results.getString("person_in_charged");
    String status = results.getString("status");

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
       new Object [][]){
            {id, date_collected, date_disposed, person_in_charged, status}
       },
       new String [] {
             "ID", "Date collected", "Date disposed", "person in charged", 
             "status"
       }
     )); 
                
     jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        
     if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
      }
 }
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

**Summary of the solution:**

Solved by **Usagi Miyamoto** and **isaace**

The solution was to create the **List** this way

```
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>()
```

**Reason:**

**List** is an **interface**, an abstract, and cannot be instantiated directly

**ArrayList** is a **class** that **implements** List

Complete solution of **Usagi Miyamoto**

```
// to hold the data
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

// loop through the ResultSet
while(results.next())
{
    String id = results.getString("id");
    String date_collected = results.getString("date_collected");
    String date_disposed = results.getString("date_disposed");
    String person_in_charged = results.getString("person_in_charged");
    String status = results.getString("status");

    // add a new row of data
    data.add(new Object[] {id, date_collected, date_disposed, person_in_charged, status});
}

// after the loop: set the data as the model
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    // convert from List to array
    data.toArray(new Object[][data.size()],
    // column headers
    new String [] { "ID", "Date collected", "Date disposed", "person in charged", "status" }
)); 

// other details from your code: moved outside of the loop...
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0)
{
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cumulating the data, something like this:

```
// to hold the data
List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>();

// loop through the ResultSet
while(results.next())
{
    String id = results.getString("id");
    String date_collected = results.getString("date_collected");
    String date_disposed = results.getString("date_disposed");
    String person_in_charged = results.getString("person_in_charged");
    String status = results.getString("status");

    // add a new row of data
    data.add(new Object[] {id, date_collected, date_disposed, person_in_charged, status});
}

// after the loop: set the data as the model
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    // convert from List to array
    data.toArray(new Object[][data.size()],
    // column headers
    new String [] { "ID", "Date collected", "Date disposed", "person in charged", "status" }
)); 

// other details from your code: moved outside of the loop...
jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

if (jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0)
{
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Usagi,

Thanks for answering. I've got a problem on line 2 
on List<Object[]> data = new List<>();

I had to import java.util.List 
The error on declaration "List is abstract cannot be instantiated.

Is there a way I can Instantiate List?

Comment: you should do this: List<Object[]> data = new ArrayList<>(). In Java, List is an interface. That is, it cannot be instantiated directly. ArrayList is a class that implements List

Comment: Thanks Usagi and issace for helping

Answer (score 1):

The DefaultTableModel should be created and set outside of the loop.

```
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

    model.addColumn("you column names");
    model.addColumn("another column name");
    //you can add all your column headers here      

    JTable table = new JTable();

    table.setModel(model);

   while(rs.next())
    {
         String id = results.getString("id");
         String date_collected = results.getString("date_collected");
         String date_disposed = results.getString("date_disposed");
         String person_in_charged = results.getString("person_in_charged");
         String status = results.getString("status");


         model.addRow(new Object[]{id, date_collected, date_disposed, person_in_charge, status });
    }
```

and continue with the rest of your code here.

Comment: Thanks isaace for the help. Sorry for late response. I already  had forgotten this problem.